# Why does jdbc driver missing in war some times when a war file created in grails?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

When I run my grails application in development mode everything works fine. But when I create a war file and deploy it to the webserver, I get the following error?

```
[http-bio-8080-exec-20] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:486)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:144)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.getTargetConnection(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:403)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:376)
        at $Proxy66.getMetaData(Unknown Source)
```

JDBC driver `ojdbc6.jar` file is missing when I opened the war archive. My previous working deploys have the jar file in war archive lib directory. What could be the reason? I use grails version 2.4.4.

Here is the `BuildConfig.grrovy`

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
//grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
//grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
//grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
//grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

//Start company specific
//set plugin directory (needed for having plugins in perforce)
grails.project.plugins.dir="./plugins"
grails.project.class.dir = "work/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "work/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "work/test-reports"
//set the grails work dir (contains proxy configuration file)
grails.project.work.dir="./work"
//End company specific

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "ivy" // or maven
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.8'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:2.1.5"
        compile ":quartz2:2.1.6.2"
        compile ":mail:1.0.7"
        compile ":filterpane:2.4.7"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
//        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your `BuildConfig.groovy` look like and how are you creating the war?

Comment: Included `BuildConfig.groovy` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your buildconfig.groovy and let me know. I've refined my buildconfig.groovy for many projects I have in production under Grails and that was an issue before Grails 2.4, if I didn't use the configuration I'm telling you, the war wouldn't contain the jar. I guess there are other solutions but mine is getting it from the repository I tell you in the dependencies block. I'm using jdbc41 for postgreSQL but for ojdb I found you could use `'cn.guoyukun.jdbc:oracle-ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3.0'` instead. Anyway you can check at [mvnrepository](http://mvnrepository.com/) for the most appropiate version for you.

```
repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    mavenLocal()
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()
    // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
    //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
}

 dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
    // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
    runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
    test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"
}
```

Hope I've helped!

Comment: Yes, adding it to dependencies does the job. But, may be because of my company policies, it could not fetch it from the repository.

Comment: [https://maven-repository.com/artifact/cn.guoyukun.jdbc/oracle-ojdbc6/11.2.0.3.0]. `clean` and `compile --refresh-dependencies` every time before the war creation fixing the issue.